# Constraint in UIView class crash application

Tags: objective-c, ios10

I have created a UIView class:

UIViewClass.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UIViewClass : UIView

@end
```

UIViewClass.m

```
#import "UIViewClass.h"

@implementation UIViewClass

- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{

    UIButton *doneBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [doneBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(doneAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [doneBtn setTitle:@"Done" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [doneBtn.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"AvenirNext-Bold" size:20]];
    doneBtn.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 75, 40);
    doneBtn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [self addSubview:doneBtn];

    [self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint
                      constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-180-[doneBtn]"
                      options:0
                      metrics:nil
                      views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(doneBtn)]];

    return self;

}

@end
```

and I call it 
`UIViewClass *viewClass = [[UIViewClass alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,150,150)];`

When I try to build it, it built with no errors but when I launch the app, the app crashes. I know that the problem is the constraint because without it, it run smoothly. Can someone tell me what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not invoking the superclass. Always invoke the superclass (super) initializer first.

Further Reading:
[Concepts in Objective-C Programming](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Initialization/Initialization.html)

Example:

```
self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
```

Comment: can you explain? like what do I need to add to my code

Comment: that's not the issue becuase it works fine without the constraint

Comment: @AlmogHamdani You want to do it anyway.

Comment: @AlmogHamdani so without the constraint you can see the button? You also add UIViewClass as a subview to another view?

Comment: I have fixed it using what @shallowThought said, by the way thank you dude.